# When different threads access a static method, are objects declared in that method local or shared in java

Tags: java, concurrency

When different threads access a static method, are objects declared in that method local or shared between threads in java?

Also,  is it safe to call `thread.interrupt()` on a thread that is doing i/o?

Comment: Those are two separate questions and should be asked in two separate posts.

Comment: calling thread.interrupt on threads doing io in a static method

Comment: still two separate questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Objects declared inside a `static` method are not shared between threads.  Objects defined outside the method as `static` are shared.

So:

```
private static Object thisIsShared;

public static void myMethod() {
    Object thisIsNotShared = new Object();
}
```

If you're going to be calling `interrupt()` on threads doing I/O you should look at using classes that implement [the `InterruptableChannel` interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/InterruptibleChannel.html).

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the interrupt() -->

It depends on how you are going to handle interrupts on the IO thread. Despite its name, interrupt() does nothing more than passing an interrupt message to the given thread. It does not imply to cease operation as fast as possible. The receiving thread will see this message and raise InterruptedException. How it will then react to the situation is utterly in its power. It can choose to ignore it, restart itself, shut down, whatever.

Interrupts are generally used when you need to tell another thread that something fundamental has changed and that the current context of execution might no longer be valid or desirable or possible or whatever you need.

Answer (score 1):

Variables declared in a static method are NOT shared between threads.  When a static method does not modify any static or otherwise shared objects, it is threadsafe -- meaning multiple threads can invoke the method and nothing bad will happen.

[Looking here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29), a lot of things can go wrong when interrupting a thread.  But it does not seem like having a thread invoke a static method is one of them.  I could be wrong.

Comment: `static` has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is: static vs non-static, it doesn't matter.

Local variables are always local to that invocation of the method, regardless of whether the method is static or not. They are allocated on the stack and popped off the stack (and unreferenceable) after the method exits.

As for your second question, read the docs,

> http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html

If you are using non-blocking IO, then yes calling `interrupt()` may make sense depending on what you expect (again, read the docs). If you are doing blocking IO, calling `interrupt()` will have no effect.

Answer (score 1):

It is safe to call `thread.interrupt()` on a thread that is doing I/O as long as the I/O is being done on an [interruptable channel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/nio/channels/InterruptibleChannel.html).

> If this thread is blocked in an I/O operation upon an interruptible channel then the channel will be closed, the thread's interrupt status will be set, and the thread will receive a ClosedByInterruptException.

As per [java.lang.Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

> When different threads access a static method, are objects declared in
>   that method local or shared between threads in java?

Objects declared in any method are local to the method. It doesn't make any difference whether the method is static or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Variables declared in static or non static method aren't shared between different threads.